# Redirect to 404 page programmatically using asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I have created a Asp.net MVC application. Now required 404 handling.

Have updated global.asax and display 404 page based on status code. Also added customErrors property in web.config. Its working fine.

Now I would like to redirect to 404 programmatically when any thing not match with our requirement.

i.e.

```
if(!valid) 
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Page404");
}
```

It's working fine but there are 2 status one is 301 & then 404. So how can I prevent 301? I just need 404.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `web.config`, add:

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.shtml" />
</customErrors>
```

This will redirect on 404.shtml page when requested resource is not found.

**Note:** No need to programmatically redirect users for such situation.

---

**EDIT:**
I literally suggest:

```
if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404) {
  // handle this
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Simply return from your action:

```
return HttpNotFound();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. In a case where you query the database whilst servicing a result, and find an object with the user-specified ID does not exist, you DO need to programmatically redirect the user to a 404 page (or similar action).

Answer (score 2):

Just throw out a 404 in the status code:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound
```