# Redirect to home/index when 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I want to redirect to home/index when an user tries to get access to a resource that doesn't exist.

Yes, there are a lot of questions about how to solve this problem. I read them, but their solutions don't work for me.

Now, I'm trying this on `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/Home/Index" responseMode="Redirect" /> 
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

But, when I try to access this URL, http://host01/Views/ConnectBatch/Create.cshtml, I get the default 404 page.

Maybe the problem is in `path="~/Home/Index"` but I tried with `path="~/"` and I get the same default 404 page.

Any idea?

Comment: Error filters... global filters. That kind of thing

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious: you're using IIS/IIS Express, and not Cassini?

Comment: I'm also surprised you're getting a 404 rather than a 403; directory browsing is supposed to be forbidden by default in an ASP.NET MVC project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I have solved my problem. Maybe others answers can solved it but I have tested a few of them (I have added a comment on answers that I've tested saying that, that answer doesn't work for me).

I have added this in `Web.config` inside `<system.web>`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/"/>
</customErrors>
```

I want to redirect to /Home/Index when an user doesn't find a resource.

Answer (score 3):

There lot of thread in stackoverflow but my case ..working this

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.shtml" />
</customErrors>
```

Orginal [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702631/redirect-to-404-page-programatically-using-asp-net-mvc)

> Or

You Should Handle The error in Code behind Like this (global.asax)

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            Response.Clear();

            var routedata= new RouteData();
            routedata.DataTokens["area"] = "ErrorArea"; // In case controller is in another area
            routedata.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
            routedata.Values["action"] = "NotFound";

            IController c = new ErrorsController();
            c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routedata));
        }
    }
}
```

In your error Controller Like this

```
public sealed class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        ActionResult result;

        object model = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            result = View(model);
        else
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeController");
    }
}
```

Orginal [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

You could try ~/ or ~/home/index. Or a long shot would be changing the web.config in the views folder

**update**
Or maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203918/catch-404-error-in-mvc4) is the way to go, my first instinct when I read your question was a handler

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try to use :

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

From :
[ASP.NET MVC 404 handling and IIS7 <httpErrors>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554844/asp-net-mvc-404-handling-and-iis7-httperrors)

And That my Help :

[ASP.NET MVC 404 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling/9026907#9026907)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using Session variables...
initialize Session variable when the resource is available

for example:

```
Session["user_name"] = resource.name;
```

Check this variable in the page-load function

```
if(Session["user_name"] == null)
  Respon.Redirect("login.aspx");
```